# iOS - UIPickerView disable component

Tags: ios, components, uipickerview

I have a dynamic `UIPickerView` that work like that :

- Begin with only 1 component
- When select a row, add a new component

For precision, by component I mean column.

I want only my last added component to be actived. Others one should be completely disabled and should not even be able to scroll or be able to select rows.

I already know how to add a component dynamically but I have no idea to disable one.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to disable a component without implementing it entirely by yourself, but what you could do is display only one component at a time and add an accessory view with a "back" button, so for example, if you were selecting a location, you would show a component with states, and when the user selected a state, you would replace that component with one with city names for that state and add a "back" button for them to backtrack if necessary.  That is the cleanest solution I know of for what you want to do.

If you absolutely have to "disable" a component, you will have no choice but to subclass UIPickerView and override the touchesBegan:withEvent and similar methods to basically ignore touches to other components.  To "disable" you could lay a gray layer with alpha < 1.0 over the disabled component.  I have to warn you this can get ugly and have unforseen and undesirable consequences if not implemented properly.  Good luck.

Comment: I already thought about this solution but unfortunately, this is not up to me, my boss want to implement it this way :(

Comment: I edited my answer to describe how you could "disable" a component.  I can't recommend it, but it is possible.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I created two UIViews, one to hold the picker and a subview with user input enabled to captures touches. place this over the component and you can toggle userInputEnabled as needed.